# Suggested UI flows for request -> delay -> response?

Tags: google-app-maker

Before I dive in too deep any guidelines on best practice for UI flows where the response is delayed from request? Ie, submit job, wait 10 - 45 seconds, get job response back?

Job would be calling out to a REST endpoint, I'd love to have a UI update when job is done.

With firebase for example you can surface job status asynchronously to let user know when report is ready. I see the binding to Cloud SQL, but not clear on how updates on Cloud SQL job record flow back to UI.

Answer (score 1):

There is high probability that user will leave the app by the time when job is done, so you can consider notifying user by email with job result. For patient users you can show [snackbar popup](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/ui/popups#snackbar):

```javascript
google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler(function() {
    // set snackbar success text
    app.popups.Snackbar.visible = true;
  })
  .withFailureHandler(function(error) {
    // set snackbar error text
    app.popups.Snackbar.visible = true;
  })
  .doLooongJob();
```

It seems that this article by material design appears to be relevant - https://material.io/design/communication/confirmation-acknowledgement.html#acknowledgement